"PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:" While Installing torchaudio in Anaconda
I was trying to install torchaudio inside an Anaconda environment with the command conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch -c conda-forge, I get the error:,
I got the error below:

Channels:
pytorch
nvidia
conda-forge
defaults
Platform: linux-aarch64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
torchaudio==2.0.2
Current channels:
https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch
https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
defaults
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I have added conda-forge to my list of channels and got the same error. Can anyone help me?
I have added conda-forge to my list of channels and got the same error. Can anyone help me?
